# SharePoint Online search result is different on filename search with and without asterisk wild character

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, search-results

I have two files, BTWaste.RN_SpecSheet.pdf and BTWasteCI.RN_SpecSheet.pdf, which are on same library, same folder and upload at the same time. I use "filename: btwaste" and "filename: btwaste*" to search.

I expect result are the same for both search. Why only one file on search result for "filename: btwaste" searching?

I remove dot on file name, BTWasteRN_SpecSheet.pdf and BTWasteCIRN_SpecSheet.pdf, result is still the same.

[image: With asterisk search result]

[image: Without asterisk search result]

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, this is the correct search results

**(*)** as a wildcard, it means that as long as the file named with "btwaste" begins, it will be searched. Therefore, the BTWaste.RN_specsheet.pdf and BTWasteCI.RN_specsheet.pdf can be searched.

"BTWaste.RN_specsheet.pdf" is composed of **"BTWaste", "RN_specsheet" and "pdf"**, while "BTWasteCI.RN_specsheet.pdf" is composed of **"BTWasteCI", "RN_specsheet" and "pdf"**. Therefore, when you search for "btwaste", SharePoint will only display "BTWaste.RN_specsheet.pdf". In other words, **“BTWasteCI”** and **“BTWaste”** are considered two different keywords in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Understand "BTWaste.RN_specsheet.pdf" is composed of "BTWaste", "RN_specsheet" and "pdf".  But, I remove dot from both file names and change to BTWasteRN_specsheet.pdf and BTWasteCIRN_specsheet.pdf, result is still the same.